# Execute PL/SQL on alternate schema

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I was logged in as UserA and was trying to execute the following

```
alter session set current_schema = UserB;
begin
    execute immediate 'Insert into UserB.tablea (c1, c2) values (val1,val2)'
end;
```

I keep getting this error

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at line 3
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
       without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
       attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
       system privileges.
       When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this error may occur
       if the user was granted the necessary privilege at a higher label
       than the current login.
*Action:   Ask the database administrator to perform the operation or grant
       the required privileges.
       For Trusted Oracle users getting this error although granted the
       the appropriate privilege at a higher label, ask the database
       administrator to regrant the privilege at the appropriate label.
```

I do have alter_session privledges on UserA and insert privledges on UserB.tablea as UserA. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be confused about what "set current_schema = xyz". This just saves you from having to type the username when referencing an object in another schema, it doesn't give you any new privileges.

```
SQL> select * from scott.dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC           OPTION
---------- -------------- ------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> select * from dept;
select * from dept
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> alter session set current_schema = scott;

Session altered.

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC           OPTION
---------- -------------- ------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

So, you'll need to get grant insert on UserB.tablea to the user running the code. As a test, simply run the

```
Insert into UserB.tablea (c1, c2) values (val1,val2);
```

outside of the begin/end block.

Comment: I have granted insert on UserB.tablea to the user running the code and have attempted to run the insert command as an SQL command outside of the PL/SQL block. It still gives me the same error...

Comment: Are there other permissions necessary to be able to insert to other users?

Comment: Nope: GRANT INSERT on <table_name> to <other user>; is all you need. Can you verify you have the privileges using - as the user trying to do the insert run this: select * from ALL_TAB_PRIVS where table_schema = 'USERB' ? Look for a row where TABLE = TABELA and PRIVILEGE = INSERT.

Comment: There are 3 rows with TABLE_NAME = Tablea and PRIVILEGE = INSERT/SELECT/UPDATE...

Comment: You were correct. Upon closer inspection of the problem, I realized that I had overlooked something.... We use a sequence for inserting on this table... I never granted select on the sequence to USERA... Thanks alot. Looking at that table helped ^_^

Comment: @MichaelKenworthy - ah, going by your example I thought you were specifying constants; I didn't even think about sequences. Glad you got that sorted out.